# Installing learnyounode

Tags: javascript, node.js, installation

hy everybody I'm trying to install learnyounode on my pc but as soon as i write
npm -g install learnyounode
and I click enter ... this is what happens

C:\Users\My name>npm install -g learnyounode
npm ERR! Unexpected token '.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\My name\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-03T13_49_21_895Z-debug-0.log

does anybody know what shall I do?
thanks
L

I expected to see the learnyounode pannel as in the picture[image: learnyounodepannel]

Comment: `learnyounode` was last published 2 years ago... I would not suggest using this to learn Node.js.

Comment: I agree with caTS, publishing date should be a main parameter of choice.
Beside that, try  checking your npm and node version with `npm -v` and `node -v`. If it doesn't display the version number, install them both (always better to install node with "nvm" package for node versioning).
If the problem persist, please post the content of your logs (2022-11-03T13_49_21_895Z-debug-0.log).
By the way, the error message tells you that you you have an `Unexpected token '.'` wich means a wrong character ".". So double check if you have any dot or strange syntax error.